# Reusing code from Hartl Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I've almost completed Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial.  Absolutely loved it, and loving what I've learnt about Rails.

It occurred to me, that I could reuse most of what we've done for the other app ideas that I have.  We have great user registration, authentication, security and testing.  It would be 'straightforward' to modify what I have here for other purposes.

I just want to ask if this is a standard practice when building new apps (reusing what you already have), and if there any gotchas or things I've not considered in looking to do so?

Loving getting back into coding, and can't wait to get my first idea out into the wild!

Answer (score 2):

These are the standard practices. But of course it all depends on the requirements, based on requirements you need to modify some things.

Also you can refer guides.rubyonrails.org for more.

Comment: thanks for the resource Aashish, I will check it out!

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I found useful to do is create a base app that includes an Authentication system such as from the Rails Tutorial book, basic templates with a navigation bar and footer and a home and about page. And I connect Bootstrap. I call it Baseapp and when I start a new app I just copy it to a new folder and rename it. Then start customizing it from there.

Comment: great thanks Steve.  I figured that made a lot of sense but didn't know if there might be some reason not to do so...

Comment: No. What you might do is start each app completely from scratch for a few times until you have it down. Then create your base app the way you like it and use that for the rest of your apps.